# Fundamental vector field and moment map for action on mathematical pendulum.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions, vector-fields, moment-map

I am trying to compute the [moment map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_map), for an action.

As I understand it if I have a configuration space which is given by a manifold $M$ and an action $\rho_g \colon M \to M$, it induces an action on the phase space

$(\rho_{g^{-1}})^* : T^*M \to T^*M$, $(\rho_{g^{-1}})^* : (q,p) \mapsto (gq, (\rho_{g^{-1}})^*(p))$.

Then we can compute the [fundamental vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_vector_field).

Let $X\in \mathfrak{g}=T_eG$ be the an element of the Lie algebra, we then have

$X^\#_{(q,p)}=\frac{d}{dt}_{\vert_{t=0}} \rho_{exp(tX)^{-1}}^*(q,p)$.

I was trying do do an example to understand how it works.

The mathematical pendulum with coordinate $(\phi,\theta)$, and the action (with $G=S^1$)

$\rho_g : S^2 \to S^2$, $\rho_{\theta}:(\phi_0,\theta_0) \mapsto (\phi_0,\theta_0+\theta)$.

But in practice, I am confused as to how exactly calculat $(\rho_{-\theta})^*$ and $X^\#_{(q,p)}$.